# MySQL indexation issue

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have created the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE citycodes
    (
     city VARCHAR(30),
     code VARCHAR(10),
     INDEX idx_code (code),
     INDEX idx_city (city)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I know that this query will have poor performance due to the lack of indexation.

```
SELECT city FROM citycodes WHERE code = 37040
```

But I have improved the select by doing this:
I have added a primary key to the city column. Should i run my query like this:

```
SELECT city, code FROM citycodes WHERE code = "37040" AND city LIKE "C%"
```

Any hint will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: why don't you just make the city code column the primary key ? and run the first query. It will be faster as primary keys are always indexed

Comment: You want an index on the column you are going to apply your WHERE or JOIN to. So in your case you want to index the `code` column and leave your query as is. It should also probably be a primary key anyway which is then always indexed.

Comment: @nathvarun basically i just need to add PRIMARY KEY (code) in the create table statement. and after this i can run the first query?

Comment: You should add a primary key to a unique column in your table. 
In this case the city code column would be a good choice. 
After you add the primary key all your queries involving this table will be faster.

Comment: @nathvarun the `city` does not llok like a good candidate for PK in this table. I expect many city codes to exist in a city.

Comment: I have asked him to use the city CODE column and not the city column. I have no idea about the data. I am assuming the city code column is unique. If the person asking the question is willing to improve his query i'm assuming he understands the basic requirement of the primary key column being unique.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "indexing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few hints to speed up performance of that table:

> ```
> city VARCHAR(30),
> ```

You may wish to consider changing this `VARCHAR` to a `CHAR` field. The database will increase in size somewhat, but unless you have every metropolis, town, and mud hut village in the world in your database, it won't make more than a few MiB difference in storage, but will potentially [increase indexing performance by up to 20%](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field).

> ```
> code VARCHAR(10),
> ```

In your example, the code you gave was numeric, so why not use an `INT` (or other integer data type) instead? You will see another significant boost in performance as a result.

> ```
> INDEX idx_code (code),
> INDEX idx_city (city)
> ```

Put your `PRIMARY KEY` on the column that will be queried more often (or, if in doubt, with the smaller numeric field, `code`). Note that this implies the values in that column must be `UNIQUE`. If you will be querying the other field (i.e., to determine the city's code based its name), add a `KEY` to that as well.

> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

MyISAM is indeed probably fine for this purpose, as the table is probably read-heavy, would not require locking, and (if you heed my above comments) will have fixed-length rows.

Here is the modified table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE citycodes (
    code INT PRIMARY KEY,
    city CHAR(30),
    KEY(city)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Last but not least, consider your algorithm:

This is a very simple key/value table, and probably a pretty small one at that. If you are concerned about performance here, perhaps the more prudent question is, **"why does the performance of this table matter so much to my application?"**

Look at your algorithm, and look at the type and number of queries you are making. Even if you optimize this query to run in half the time, it's still going to be prohibitively slow if you run the `SELECT` thousands of time in a loop, for example. The best way to optimize a query is to alter your algorithm so you don't have to *run* the query at all. (Or run it just once, and cache the full result in your application, where accesses will be far faster in your language's native data structures).

If you rarely query this table directly, but instead pull in the columns in `JOIN`s, you may consider de-normalizing your table schema, to just use the `city` name in your other table(s) that require it. I wouldn't recommend this unless its absolutely necessary, as it could increase other tables' storage requirements significantly, and require extensive `UPDATE` queries if one of your cities ever changes its name. But, [de-normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) can still be a valid design decision if considered carefully.

Comment: thank you @type_outcast . Excellent explanation. I will give it a try and then let you know how it behaves.